# Preventing body from too high acceleration

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am currently creating an Andengine game which features a ball and a blocker just like pong, except in my game the world and blocker aren't squares and are instead circles.

Right now when the ball bounces off of the blocker all physics seem to check out alright but when I move the blocker really fast to the destination and the blocker hits the ball the ball goes flying off the screen at insane speeds.

How would I go about keeping the ball's velocity at the same speed all the time while keeping current physics?

Answer (score 0):

Don't remember exact code but the logic is:
in onManageedUpdate check the speed of your object, then if speed exceed some value you are happy with set the linear speed to this good value.

Other solution could be that you use ContactListener and in postSolve or endContact you set velocity to desired one.

Also check why this speed after bounce is that fast. Is it because a blocker is moving really fast? Does it also happen when blocker is moving slowly?